# Trouble with getting a sort to work within a view with views_bonus_pack

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

This is my first time using Views in Drupal and am finding that no matter what I do, I can't seem to get my output to sort on any field at all.

I'm using the views_bonus_pack to create xml output, but not sure if that matters.

I've tried the post date field, the node Id field, the node title field, and... the output is always the same.

Any ideas?

[Update, here are screenshots of what I'm working with]

[http://emberapp.com/evanmcd/images/settings-2/sizes/m.png](http://emberapp.com/evanmcd/images/settings-2/sizes/o)
http://emberapp.com/evanmcd/images/untitled/sizes/m.png
[image]

And, here's the resulting XML
http://www.mapendo.org/media_viewer/items.xml

Thanks to anyone who can help.

- Evan

Comment: Did you try changing the style of the view to table, in example, and see if you can sort the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort criteria are listed to the right side.

[Views screenshot http://img.skitch.com/20100715-jcfqnsu8mty6r7mexeyxsis4f4.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100715-jcfqnsu8mty6r7mexeyxsis4f4.png)

If you changed the sort criteria trying to get differently sorted data without to obtain any difference, then there are just two possibilities:

1. The sort criteria are not used for feeds; it's rather improbable.
2. The style plugin module has an issue, and it's not working as it should.

Comment: Yeah, just added a larger version of the settings image above, showing the selected sort. I also added a link to the resulting XML, showing that the sort is not happening.  Thanks.

Comment: I kept trying to obtain differently sorted data, hoping that I was following the same steps you followed. I have not been able to get any result. I think that the style plugin is not using any of the sort criteria used by the view.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right.  Seems to be a bug or a conscious lack of implementation.  I will need to manage sorting in the Flash I am using to display the data.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If Views Bonus Pack is implementing a style, each style has its own settings that change the output produced by the style. When you click on the wheel close the style name, you would see some settings fields for that purpose.

[Views style http://img.skitch.com/20100711-x3ag3ew6q33r3sje36qdnd4fti.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100711-x3ag3ew6q33r3sje36qdnd4fti.jpg)

[Views style settings http://img.skitch.com/20100711-mfa6xnx3ca5261uxyq5w6j75g8.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100711-mfa6xnx3ca5261uxyq5w6j75g8.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I don't see any options to specify a Table style.  See above, as I've added screenshots.  Need the output to be XML, not sure if that's possible with the Table style.  Thanks.

Comment: The table style is included with Views; the purpose of the screenshot was to show what I was referring to. Different view styles show different fields.